# Python 3 writing to DBF (dBase IV with Memo)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbf, dbase

I need to write to dBase IV dbf file with memo fields in Python3, but cannot find a suitable module to do this.

Packages that I have tried:

Simpledbf - Read-only

dbf - Does not support dBase IV

dbfpy - Does not support Python 3

dbfpy3 - Does not support dBase IV

YDbf - Does not support memo fields

pyshp - Cannot work with dbf files only (Without .shp and .shx)

Any suggestions on what to try next are welcome.